# React- Lodash isEqual returning false even when objects are the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am trying to prevent rerender of my child component by using React Memo. However, since react memo uses shallow comparison, I tried bringing in lodash _.isEqual method in order to do a deep comparison to prevent rerender if the values of the object does not change. However, even when the values of the object does not change, it return false. Is there any reason why? I would get that if the comparison is shallow as the object reference is different, but why is it that the deep comparison returns false?

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button, Empty, List, Spin, Menu, Dropdown, Skeleton } from 'antd';
import OpportunityDrawer from './Forms/OpportunityDrawer';
import { FileImageOutlined, MoreOutlined, MailOutlined, IdcardOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import RequirementHistory from './RequirementHistory';

const _ = require("lodash");

function RequirementTimeline({ requirements }) {


    const actions = (requirement) => (
        <Menu>
            <Menu.Item>
                <OpportunityDrawer data={requirement}
                    button_name='Edit Requirement'
                    title='Edit Requirement'
                    component='RequirementUpdate'
                    button_type='update' />
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item><OpportunityDrawer data={requirement.customer_requirement_id}
                button_name='Delete Requirement'
                title='Delete Requirement'
                component='RequirementDelete'
                button_type='delete' /></Menu.Item>
            {requirement.file ?
                <Menu.Item>
                    <Button type="text" shape="circle" size="small"><a href={requirement.file}><FileImageOutlined /></a></Button> File
                </Menu.Item>
                : null}
            <Menu.Item><RequirementHistory history={requirement.history} /></Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item><CalendarDrawer
                button_name='Create Reminder'
                title='When Shall we remind you?'
                component='CreateReminder'
                task_title={`Reminder [Requirements ID: ${requirement.customer_requirement_id}]`}
                content={`Please remember to follow up on Requirement [${requirement.customer_requirement_id}]`}
            />
            </Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
    )

    console.log('hi')

    return (
        requirements.length ?
            <List
                size="large"
                dataSource={requirements}
                renderItem={item => (
                    <List.Item>
                        <div className='requirement-grid'>
                            <p className='requirement-title'><MailOutlined />{item.requirements}</p>
                            <p className='requirement-description'><IdcardOutlined /> ID: {item.customer_requirement_id}</p>
                            <Dropdown placement="bottomRight" overlay={() => actions(item)}>
                                <Button size='small' shape='circle' className='requirement-button'><MoreOutlined /></Button>
                            </Dropdown>
                        </div>
                    </List.Item>
                )}
            />
            : <Empty image={Empty.PRESENTED_IMAGE_SIMPLE} />
    )
}

export default React.memo(RequirementTimeline,
    (prevProps, nextProps) => {
        console.log(_.isEqual(prevProps.requirements, nextProps.requirements));
        return _.isEqual(prevProps.requirements, nextProps.requirements)
    })
```

Essentially, the contents of the requirement props does not change. In the parent component, the data changes, but the nested object 'requirement' which is part of the data does not change.

For example, what I did was update another part of the data, while leaving the contents of the 'requirement' the same.

```
{ project_name: /* this is changed */ ,
  requirements: [ /* this is not changed */
}
```

^ do note that when I say 'this is not changed', I mean the contents, not the reference as I do understand that the reference is changed, since a new api call is made after changing 'project_name' to attain the new data to store. However, since the contents of 'requirements' is not changed, shouldn't it evaluate to true for lodash's _.isEqual method?

I am using React Memo. Do advise if there is a better way to prevent rerender. I know that deep comparisons are costly, but I need to prevent the child components from rerendering unnecessarily as it hinders performance and causes the website to slow down. Ideally, I would only want to rerender those parts of the data that changed.

Comment: how many elements are you rerendering, react is designed to handle alot rerenders, are you sure the performance is really slowing down that much?

Comment: @jason did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The props will be different because there are identifiers that change when they're updated. It's used to compare prev and next props usually and prevent additional renders faster.

Do you have another property that you can include? Like compare `prevProps.requirements.id` or use hooks to let react pick for you?

When you log next and prev props, you can see they're not equal, or if you log them after calling JSON.stringify,

I would also reconsider needing React.memo. React is already very good at this, and adding extra things can get on the way.